# PHP AJAX JQuery attachment email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, email-attachments

Just looking for some advice really. I have a small form on my website which i'm building:

- Name
- Email
- Number
- CV (attachment)

I have done forms before, however with the added attachment i'm not sure how to go about it.

Im used to using jQuery's serialize function. Is there something similar i can use to post within my Ajax call? I cant seem to find much info on the web..

Answer (score 1):

For AJAX requests, you cannot really use `.serialize()` functions. You need to use `FormData()`. You can also put a progress bar. We need to check for the support first:

```
function supportAjaxUploadWithProgress() {
  return supportFileAPI() && supportAjaxUploadProgressEvents() && supportFormData();

  function supportFileAPI() {
    var fi = document.createElement('INPUT');
    fi.type = 'file';
    return 'files' in fi;
  };

  function supportAjaxUploadProgressEvents() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return !! (xhr && ('upload' in xhr) && ('onprogress' in xhr.upload));
  };

  function supportFormData() {
    return !! window.FormData;
  }
}
```

The next step is to submit the form using AJAX:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form-id');
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

You have to have these HTML:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('the-form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
  var formData = new FormData(form);

  formData.append('file', file);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Add any event handlers here...
  xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
  xhr.send(formData);

  return false; // To avoid actual submission of the form
}
```

```html
<form id="the-form" action="/upload/path" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="file" type="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

More info: [Ridiculously simple Ajax uploads with FormData](https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata/).